# How to secure spring boot webflux webclient with ssl

Tags: ssl, keycloak, spring-webclient

i am working on an web app which contains a keycloak authenticated spring webflux webclient that communicate with a rest microservice after throw jwt. this web app is working very well on local, but when i deploy it on VPS and secure it with self signed SSL it doesn't.
the stack and yaml files and configurations are below.

**Stack Trace of the webclient**

```
 [80951c4f-3]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/login/oauth2/code/keycloak?st                     ate=_OL6ieI7ZLkxdwNUn-_r1KJW6iQpe-0UtgHR_t6R7MQ%3D&session_state=2de93ae4-4edb-4cc7-ba54-f3cd2bc78656&code=c2762a41-f07e-48c5-b548-4bfcaae7d7c7.2de93ae4-4edb-4cc7-ba54-f3cd2bc7                     8656.54771ced-5411-4aff-9cd6-3553871f035e"

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to fin                     d valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBu                     ilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.9.                     jar!/:5.3.9]
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST https://185.7.212.159:8543/auth/realms/haditvpas/protocol/openid-connect/token [DefaultWebClient]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/login/oauth2/code/keycloak?state=_OL6ieI7ZLkxdwNUn-_r1KJW6iQpe-0UtgHR_t6R7MQ%3D&session_state=2de93ae4-4edb-4cc7-ba54-f3cd2bc78656&code=c2762                     a41-f07e-48c5-b548-4bfcaae7d7c7.2de93ae4-4edb-4cc7-ba54-f3cd2bc78656.54771ced-5411-4aff-9cd6-3553871f035e" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

**yaml file for restful microservice**

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:ssl-server.jks
    key-store-password: changeit
    key-store-type: JKS
    key-store-provider: SUN
    enabled: true
  port: 9090
  error:
    include-stacktrace: never

spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            registration:
                keycloak: 
                    client-id: 'PAS-client'
                    scope: openid
                    
                    client-secret: 'c16bbf0d-6281-461c-8a09-3eddeb3a229d'
                    
                    authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
                    redirectUri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            provider:
                keycloak:
                    authorizationUri: https://185.7.212.159:8543/auth/realms/haditvpas/protocol/openid-connect/auth
                    tokenUri: https://185.7.212.159:8543/auth/realms/haditvpas/protocol/openid-connect/token
                    jwkSetUri: https://185.7.212.159:8543/auth/realms/haditvpas/protocol/openid-connect/certs
##                

                    user-name-attribute: name

app-server:
    url: https://185.7.212.159:9091
```

**yaml file for weclient**

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always

spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
        host: localhost
        port: 27017
        database: production
        auto-index-creation: true
  jackson:
    date-format: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdDateFormat
    default-property-inclusion: non-null
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
                jwkSetUri: https://185.7.212.159:8543/auth/realms/haditvpas/protocol/openid-connect/certs
                issuerUri: https://185.7.212.159:8543/auth/realms/haditvpas
                tokenUri: https://185.7.212.159:8543/auth/realms/haditvpas/protocol/openid-connect/token


server:
  port: 9091
  error:
    include-stacktrace: never
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer; the problem was the keystore did not contain my ssl .crt file.